# If $B$ is a Noetherian ring and $A$ is a subring of $B$, is $B$ Noetherian as an $A$ module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $A\subset B$ and both $A$,$B$ are ring. Suppose given that $B$ is a noetherian ring then is it true that when we consider $B$ as $A$-module then it is again a noetherian $A$-module?

My effort : I think it is not true as such but unable to find an counter example.Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Your previous title wasn't very useful. I have replaced it with something more useful. Please strive to do something like this yourself on future posts. Thanks.

Comment: yes, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb Q\subseteq \mathbb R$.

Comment: That means all the infinitely many irrational number will come which will not generated by finitely many elements as $\mathbb{Q}$ module. Is it so?

Comment: Basically. If $F\subseteq E$ is a field extension, $E$ is always noetherian, but it's only a noetherian $F$ module when $[E:F]<\infty$.